# Make a negative number appear positive, but maintain actual value

Tags: angularjs

I'm going out on a whim here, but I figured I'd ask here to check.

I have an integer value that I use to determine how other elements on the page act, the actual value of the integer is important (whether it is negative or positive), however actually displaying the prefixed hyphen when it's negative isn't desired.

Is there any way to "hide" the hyphen without altering the actual value of the integer? Keeping in mind that the value is being `$watch`ed so multiplying it by -1 is out of the question.

Template:

```
<p>{{ value }}</p>
```

Directive:

```
scope.$watch('value', function() 
{
 if (scope.value > 0)
 {
   //do something
 }
 else
 {
  //do something else
 }

});
```

Added code, not that I believe it's really necessary

Comment: Can you show some code on how it's being used?

Comment: you mean `Math.abs(-1)` =>  `1` ?

Comment: @Paolo Casciello No, that would change the actual value of the number and therefore would break the functionality

Comment: @Mr.E you said you want it as absolute while showing it to user but not in the code. So when you print it use math.abs, else use it normally. o don't see the point to make the whole thing over complicated....

Comment: @Paolo Casciello It's using AngularJS so it's two-way binded, changing the HTML value will change the value used in the code.

Comment: @Mr.E oh sorry then, i don't use angular. :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use filter

```
.filter('positive', function() {
        return function(input) {
            if (!input) {
                return 0;
            }

            return Math.abs(input);
        };
    })
```

so in your template use

```
{{value | positive}}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! EDIT: Just noticed it's very slow.. I'm making a lot of changes to this value. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there any way I can do this in the controller/directive so that I'm not making thousands of dom manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it through a function like this:

**View**

```
<p>{{ positiveLookingValue() }}</p>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.positiveLookingValue = function(){
  return Math.abs($scope.value);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm watching the value through the directive as I'm making DOM manipulations based on the value of the number so this would make the directive only ever see positive values and break the functionality

Comment: Ok, so the filter solution is definitely th best one.

Comment: Yeah I guess, it depends on the purpose. Angular filters are generally slow when it comes to large amounts of data, like this situation. Anyone looking for something low key would benefit from doing it this way.